# Как заполнить базу данных MySql скриптом прописанным в конфиге Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Подскажите что нужно прописать в конфиг файле Hibernate что бы при создании новой базы она заполнялась данными из скрипт файлы import.sql. Приложение с использованием Hibernate, MySql, Spring, Tomcat, Maven.
Если базы данных не существует то она создается автоматически.

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  

<hibernate-configuration>  
<session-factory>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>  
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>  
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>

    <mapping class="controller.User" />

</session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

версия hibernate:

```
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>4.2.7.SP1</version>
```

Comment: Не думаю, что это можно сделать средствами Hibernate, Для таких целей существуют утилиты миграции, например Flyway и Liquibase.